# Logging system fails multiple times when I call logging.config.fileConfig

Tags: python, logging, python-logging

In Python 3.7.3 if you call logging.config.fileConfig multiple times the logging system silently fails.
What causes this to happen?

```
import logging.config
logging.config.fileConfig('logging.conf')
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)


logger.error("I print")
logging.config.fileConfig('logging.conf')
logger.error("I do not")
```

A workaround is to wrap each call to `logging.config.fileConfig` call in `if __name__ == '__main__':`
Is there a better approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to ensure any existing loggers aren't disabled by calling like this:

```
logging.config.fileConfig('logging.conf', disable_existing_loggers=False)
```

This is documented [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.config.html#logging.config.fileConfig).